# How to remove or replace wrapper 'col-sm-9' to 'col-sm-12' in simple from input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

```
<%= simple_form_for [blog_post, comment], remote: true do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <%= f.input :content, label: false, input_html: { rows: 7 } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

generate next code:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group text required blog_comment_content">
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <textarea rows="7" class="text required form-control form-control" placeholder="Comments" name="blog_comment[content]" id="blog_comment_content"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

How to remove or replace wrapper 'col-sm-9' to 'col-sm-12'?

Comment: The form doesn't seem to generate the `col-sm-9` are you sure you don't just have to change it in your html file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup wrapper in `config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb`.
Look at documentation for [`simple_form`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#bootstrap) and check [`example`](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying default wrappers, add a [custom](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers) wrapper `:customized_form` in simple_form setup block:

*config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb*

```
config.wrappers :customized_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :placeholder
  b.optional :maxlength
  b.optional :pattern
  b.optional :min_max
  b.optional :readonly
  b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-12 control-label'

  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-12' do |ba|
    ba.use :input, class: 'form-control'
    ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end
end
```

Then use the newly created wrapper like this:

```
simple_form_for([blog_post, comment], wrapper: :customized_form)
```